# The title of article is not showing in the reference list

Tags: bibliographies, achemso

I am using a `.bib` file for listing my references. With using Elsevier journal package, there is no problem. However, when I use ACS journal package, the title of articles in the reference list is not showing.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
 \bibliographystyle{acs}
\bibliography{name}
```

this is the .bib file

```
@ARTICLE{Breward1,
  AUTHOR = "C. J. W. Breward and P. D. Howell",
  TITLE = "The drainage of a foam lamella",
  JOURNAL = journal of fluid mechanics,
  YEAR = "2002",
  VOLUME = "458",
 PAGES = "379-406 ",
```

Much appreciated if someone can help me.

Comment: Possible other issue: your `.bib` file is missing enclosing `"` on the `JOURNAL` field.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) there is an error in your bib data, you need `"..."` around your `JOURNAL` entry data. (3) It would seem that `achemso` dictates its own bibliography style, so yours is not used. And that style suppresses titles in the bibliography. It may very well be a specific choice from the journal, something you are the author should not fight as it is not your decision and trying to change it is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 12):

The `achemso` class sets up bibliography options to follow the journal you request. JACS don't print article titles, so the class misses them out. You can force the issue if you wish with

```
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true}
```

after the `\documentclass` line. (You'll need to run LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX to see the effect.)

Comment: As noted, the class forces use of the `achemso` style as the entire point is to be used for submissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into the `achemso.bst` file and replace the code with `biochem.bst` code. If you then run the `.tex` file it will show the article name in the reference list. The order of authors, article title, year and so on can be changed inside the `.bst` file. If you search for `article` you will find the different location where you can edit the code. To change the order of things just move them around how you'd like them to be:

```
FUNCTION { article } {
  begin.bibitem
  format.authors
  format.title.article
  format.journal
  format.year.article
  format.volume.article
  format.pages.article
  format.note
  end.bibitem
}

To get the article year in bolt letters use this:

FUNCTION { format.year.article } {
  year empty$
    { }
    {
      year bold
      output
    }
  if$
}
```

Cheers

Comment: It should be mentioned that you cannot just edit a bst file without avoiding license issues. Apart from that, the journal won't care about any changes by the user.